# How can i get custom field images using GD Star Rathing plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

how can i get the image from custom field.. to display into GD star Rathing.

Link : http://www.cinema.trancelevel.com - the image from right sidebfar from Actor are not displayng -1,2,3

For example:
In sidebar i have this code , this code was build trought GD star rathing Builder to display  3 post ( actors) that have the most votes.

```
<?php wp_gdsr_render_rating_results(array(
'template_id' => 48, 
'rows' => 3, 
'select' => 'persoane', 
'hide_empty' => true, 
'min_votes' => 0, 
'min_count' => 5, 
'image_from' => 'custom', 
'image_custom' => 'img_actor', 
'image_resize_x' => 55, 
'image_resize_y' => 70, 
'rating_size' => '16', 
'rating_thumb_size' => '16'
));?>
```

How can i retrive the picture, i only retrive the Image ID... i want the atachment linkt to the picture...

Comment: Your link is broken and please explain better.

Comment: Hy celeritas , sorry for the link, i update the link now and should work.. please look at the link .. i will be aviable for discusion

Comment: Is what your trying to do is to get the GD Star Rating plugin working? What do you mean "image from custom field"? Are you trying to do data scraping?

Comment: I want to get images from custom field ... i have a field named "img_actori" 

I can retrive the image from Content, but i don't want... 

Please look now at the site the image is get from the content..

push the link Robert De Niro

Comment: Celeritas can you help me if you are kind, or explayn me wath to do

Comment: Are you using WordPress? I may not be best qualified to assist you with this problem. Hopefully someone else can.

Comment: yes im using wordpress.. i make a complex site with a few plugin ... other are pure php...

I found this code i think there are mising somting...

http://cinema.trancelevel.com/wp-content/plugins/gd-star-rating/code/t2/render.txt


The problem i think is here :
Row 142

`$row->image = get_post_meta($row->post_id, $widget["image_custom"], true);
`

Comment: ok thanks Celeritas for answering, if anny body know's the solution please post here...

I make a print scren to see how the code is BUILD:

http://cinema.trancelevel.com/2.png

All Functions: http://cinema.trancelevel.com/wp-content/plugins/gd-star-rating/info/functions.html
Thanks